# How can I make this chart in R?

Tags: r, graph-visualization

I'm researching how to make this chart in R. I have the data and I could do it in excel, but I want to make it in R too. I can´t share the data because it is private information, but I would appreciate if you could indicate useful packages or functions.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You could likely create this with the ggraph and the ggforce packages, but it wouldn't be simple. The simplest would really to use something like adobe illustrator.

Comment: This is a very customized, nonstandard chart. I would probably use ggplot2 (using `geom_point` and `scale_size_area` for the bubbles, `geom_segment` for the background horizontal lines, `geom_label` for the rectangular boxes) and `ggtext` (for the mix of bold and regular text). It will take a large amount of data wrangling preparation to specify all the boxes and might be easier in excel or powerpoint if it's a one-off.